# Merging an object created from a previous hibernate session into the current hibernate session

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have an `@ModelAttribute("myModel")` that is injected into a spring form and also stored as part of the session in a `@SessionAttribute("myModel")`.

At the controller, the model is picked up and changes merged into the @SessionAttribute.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@ModelAttribute("myModel") MyModel myModel) {
  myModel.getSomething();
  ...
}
```

The problem is that all my hibernate domain objects are LAZY.  Because the Hibernate Session that created myModel no longer exists, when I try to access someting that was not included as part of a `fetch` statement in the HQL, I get a LazyInitializationException.

Hibernate has a `merge()` method, how can I use this to merge an object created in a previous hibernate session into the current one so that all the LAZY properties can be accessed?  Or is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call merge(), and use its returned value: it's the attached entity containing the values found in the detached entity passed as argument:

```
Foo modifiedAttachedFoo = session.merge(modifiedDetachedFoo);
modifiedAttachedFoo.getLazyCollection().size(); // no problem: the entity is attached
```

Comment: ok thanks, I will give this a try.  If I do this, make some changes to `modifiedAttachedFoo`, and save it, will this be reflected in the @SessionAttribute version?

Comment: No, it won't. It's a different instance. merge() leaves its detached argument untouched, loads the attached instance with the same ID from the sesion, copies the fields from the detached to the attached, and returns the attached. Also note that you don't have to save an attached entity: it's attached, which means that all the changes you make on it are transparently, automatically persisted.

Comment: ok, that clears things up.  Is there a way to merge the attached object back into the @SessionAttribute so the next time a request is made I am pointing to the most up to date object?

Comment: No, you'll have to put the attached entity in the session again, to replace the previous one. But a better solution would be to avoid storing it in the session, and always get it from the database. That's the only way to guarantee that you're looking at the lastest value, and it makes your application stateless and thus more scalable.

Comment: OK, the issue I was having is that I am using a `@Version` column, I had trouble ensuring that the current object has not since been modified without using an @SessionAttribute.

Comment: The version field should be a hidden field of the form used to save the entity. That way, the saved detached entity will contain the version as it was when the form was generated, and you'll get an exception if it has been modified since.

Comment: oh, I should have said also.  I was having trouble when doing AJAX requests back to the server (say saving the object) and then the the form would not know about the new version number.

Comment: That's a design problem. The AJAX call should return the new version number (at least), and the form should be updated after the AJAX call.

Comment: mmmm, sounds like I really screwed it up.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you feel your session-based solution is OK, then no problem. IIRC, Spring MVC even has the notion of a conversation scope to do that, but be aware that it makes your app stateful. And statefulness can be harder to understand, maintain and scale.